# I m transmitting flex sensor values through serial port of arduino using Serial.print() function but I'm not able to read it at the receiving end

Tags: serial-port, arduino-uno

Actually in my code I'm transmitting accelerometer values as well as 4 flex sensor values. I have converted accelerometer value to 4 state as F(forward), B(backward),R(right),L(left). I am able to receive this 4 states and also I'm able to write code for these states. With these states I'm also sending flex sensor values to control servo motor remotely. But I'm not able to read those flex values as it is a varying integer. Please help me to read the flex values. I have tried Serial.read(), Serial.parseInt().

My transmitter code is:

```
int xpin = A0;
int x;
int ypin = A1;
int y;
int vcc=13;

const int flexpin1 = 2;
const int flexpin2 = 3;
const int flexpin3 = 4;
const int flexpin4 = 5;

int flex1[20];
int flex2[20];
int flex3[20];
int flex4[20];

int flexsum1=0;
int flexsum2=0;
int flexsum3=0;
int flexsum4=0;

 char state1 = 'S';
void setup() {

  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(flexpin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(flexpin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(flexpin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(flexpin4, INPUT);
  pinMode(xpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ypin, INPUT);
  pinMode(vcc, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(vcc, HIGH);
}

void loop() {


  x = analogRead(xpin);
  Serial.print("xpin=");
  Serial.print(x);
  y = analogRead(ypin);
  Serial.print("\t ypin=");
  Serial.print(y);
  if ( y > 415)
  {
    state1 = 'F';
  }
  else if (y < 315)
  {
    state1 = 'B';
  }
  else if (x > 410)
  {
    state1 = 'R';
  }

  else if (x < 310)
  {
    state1 = 'L';
  }

  else {
    state1 = 'S';
  }

 // flex readings stabelized//


for(int x=0; x<25; x++)
{
flex1[x]=analogRead(flexpin1);
flex2[x]=analogRead(flexpin2);
flex3[x]=analogRead(flexpin3);
flex4[x]=analogRead(flexpin4);
flexsum1=flexsum1+flex1[x];
flexsum2=flexsum2+flex2[x];
flexsum3=flexsum3+flex3[x];
flexsum4=flexsum4+flex4[x];

delayMicroseconds(20);
}
flexsum1=flexsum1/25;
flexsum2=flexsum2/25;
flexsum3=flexsum3/25;
flexsum4=flexsum4/25;



  Serial.print("\t\t\tflexsum1= ");
  Serial.print(flexsum1);

  Serial.print("\tflexsum2= ");
  Serial.print(flexsum2);

  Serial.print("\tflexsum3= ");
  Serial.print(flexsum3);

  Serial.print("\tflexsum4= ");
  Serial.print(flexsum4);

  Serial.print("\t state1=");
  Serial.println(state1);

delay(200);
  }
```

My receiving code:

```
#include<Servo.h>

  int IN1 = 13;
  int IN2 = 12;
  int IN3 = 7;
  int IN4 = 6;
  char state1 = 'S';
  Servo servo1, servo2, servo3, servo4;
  int flex1, flex2, flex3, flex4;
  int angle1, angle2, angle3, angle4;
  void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);
    servo1.attach(9);
    servo2.attach(8);
    servo3.attach(10);
    servo4.attach(11);
  }

  void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    while (Serial.available()) {
      delay(10);
      state1 = Serial.read();
      Serial.print(state1);

      switch (state1)
      {
        case 'F' : digitalWrite(IN1 , HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN2 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN3 , HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN4 , LOW);
          Serial.print("\tcar is moving forward ");
          delay(100);
          break;
        case 'B' : digitalWrite(IN1 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN2 , HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN3 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN4 , HIGH);
          Serial.print("\tcar is moving backward ");
          delay(100);
          break;
        case 'L' : digitalWrite(IN1 , HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN2 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN3 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN4 , HIGH);
          Serial.print("\tcar is turning left ");
          delay(100);
          break;
        case 'R' : digitalWrite(IN1 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN2 , HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN3 , HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN4 , LOW);
          Serial.print("\tcar is turning right");
          delay(100);
          break;
        case 'S' : digitalWrite(IN1 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN2 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN3 , LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN4 , LOW);
          delay(100);
          break;

      }

      if (flex1 >= 845)
      {
        flex1 = Serial.read();
        angle1 = map(flex1, 848, 1000, 0, 180);
        angle1 = constrain(angle1, 0, 90);
        servo1.write(angle1);
        Serial.print("\tangle1=");
        Serial.print(angle1);
        delay(200);
      }
      if (flex2 >= 820)
      {
        flex2 = Serial.read();
        angle2 = map(flex2, 825, 1000, 0, 180);
        angle2 = constrain(angle2, 0, 90);
        servo2.write(angle2);
        Serial.print("\tangle2=");
        Serial.print(angle2);
        delay(200);
      }
      if (flex3 >= 770)
      {
        flex3 = Serial.read();
        angle3 = map(flex3, 770, 930, 0, 180);
        angle3 = constrain(angle3, 90, 180);
        servo3.write(angle3);
        Serial.print("\tangle3=");
        Serial.print(angle3);
        delay(200);
      }
      if (flex4 >= 870)
      {
        flex4 = Serial.read();
        angle4 = map(flex4, 875, 1020, 0, 180);
        angle4 = constrain(angle4, 90, 180);
        servo4.write(angle4);
        Serial.print("\tangle4=");
        Serial.print(angle4);
        delay(200);
      }


    }
  }
```

Comment: i also tried using Serial.read() outside of if loop